# Input text fields becomes readonly in mobile view

Tags: html, readonly

I'm having problem with my code because in mobile view the input text fields doesn't have readonly attribute but when I open it in mobile view the fields becomes readonly. Here is the code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-transaction" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1">Pay</h4> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body block5">
            <form method="post" id="myLevel">
                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Amount to Pay</label>
                                <p class="text-danger">You'll be charge 5% of every Credit/Debit Card/E-Wallets Transaction. </p>
                                <input type="number" name="payment" class="form-control" id="payment" placeholder="Amount to Pay" data-error="Required!" required/> 

                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="button" id="save-transaction" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Pay</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please indent your HTML consistently, so people can read it.

Comment: Hello Renzo, welcome to SO. I feel like your post should be tagged [tag:html] as well

Comment: Why do you use contenteditable? How do you use that in the background? Are there any modifications around readonly?

Comment: You probably have some other (transparent) element hanging over your input element when you are in mobile view. Right click -> Inspect on the input field and see which elements the debugger tool selects to see if this is the case.

Comment: I'm not sure, i tried doing that but the what happens is in desktop view the text field doesn't have a readonly attribute but if in mobile view it automatically adds readonly in text fields.